# jquery selecting parent element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find href attribute of a which is in class front while the button is in 
class footer. Cant seem to make it to work.

**[JSFIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/C5R7u/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="front"> 
        <a rel="lightbox" href="asas/as/abc.html">
            <img width="200" height="125" src="http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/wp-content/uploads//2012/10/stormtroopers-sm.png"  >
        </a>
        <div class="footer">
            <button class="btn btn-mini" rel="btn_scr"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="width: 200px; height: 157px;">something here</div>
</div>
```

**JAVA**

```
$('body').on('click', '[rel=btn_scr]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).parents(".front > a").attr("href");
    alert(data);
    //console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: Use `var data = $(this).parent().prev().attr("href");`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `.front > a` is never a parent of your button. You need to traverse up to the parent (`.front`) then down to the anchor, eg

```
var data = $(this).closest('.front').find('> a').attr('href');
```

**Update:** Swapped out `parents()` for `closest()` as it's a better fit for this operation. The differences are illustrated on the [`closest()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: I know the OP tried to use .parents() for this, but .closest() makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/C5R7u/2/

```
var data = $(this).closest(".front").find('a').attr("href");
```

Comment: which is faster ? closest or parents ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(this).parents(".front").find('a').attr('href')
```

here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5R7u/5/)